# How do I match a pattern which can be anywhere in a string but not between two words?

Tags: regex, perl

Say I've two strings,

```
$string1 = "select * from auditor where name in (select 'Jack' name from employee where id = 1)";

$string2 = "select * from employee where name = 'Jack'";
```

Now, I need a RegEx to find anything enclosed inside a single quote only in where clause. i.e., in $string1 it should not match, as the single quotes are used in select clause and $string2 should match as it is used in where clause.

I tried

```
(?!select .*\'(.*)\' where)where (.*\'(.*)\')
```

Comment: if you accept to reformulate the problem, it could be "match any string inside single quote after a `where anystring = ` pattern". This solves your specific problem but doesn't really answer the question: `(?<=where)[\w\s]*=\s*'(\w*)'`

Answer (score 1):

The correct advice if the queries can be arbitrarily complex is to use a parser because SQL is context-sensitive and thus beyond the power of sane regexes.

If the `where` clauses will always be simple, you can constrain the patterns with, for example

```
if (/\bwhere\s+\w+\s+=\s+'([^']*)'/i) {
  print "  MATCH [$1]\n";
}
```

to look for a quoted string in a clause of the form `where column = 'foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
where(?!.*select|insert|update|delete).*?'([^']+)'
```

and get the result in group 1

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BJFvjr/2)

For the following 3 input:

```
$string1 = "select * from auditor where name in (select 'Jack0' name from employee where id = 1)";

$string2 = "select * from auditor where name in (blablabla 'Jack1' name from employee where id = 'jack2')";

$string3 = "select * from employee where name = 'Jack3'";
```

Output:

```
You will get jack1,jack2,jack3 in the first capture group but not won't get jack0
```

p.s: plz note that you don't need insert/update/delete these were put in the regex just to make it a bit more generic

Comment: @Aiswarya have you tried the answer, does that work for you ?